# Anyone know about a good multiple file upload script using php/mysql and ajax/javascript?

Tags: php, ajax, upload, file-upload, uploadify

as the title says: Anyone know about any good/simple multiple file upload script that uses php/mysql and ajax/javascript?

I want it to show a progress-bar, and easy customization.

I've tried [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) and [fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/), but I would want the option of adding a description and title. (and I've got some bad experience with uploaders using flash.. even if it's just a tiny bit.) Is there any other good scripts/plugins out there? or would one of them be the best choice, and rather use some time to understand the code.

Thanks in advance! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/ImageMagick <-php&imagemagick
http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/20/jquery-progress-bar-11/ <-progress bar
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ <-multiple file upload

Comment: thanks for the input, I thought the progress bar looked nice, but I can't get it to work with a upload-form. the demo worked on the t.wits.sg-website, but not on my server or xampp-install.

any idea what I'm doing wrong, or not doing?

Comment: Nope. No idea at all :P If you edit your question, or start a new question with some of the code you're trying to get to work, how far you've gotten, what errors you're getting (if any), it'd be much easier to help.